# Building a Module for Windows Azure Cloud Services?

Tags: azure

I once saw a article of how to create a Module for Windows Azure Cloud Services, such you could just import it in the ServiceDefinition.csdef

I cant find it now and been googeling for all kinds of keywords.

Anyone have some links/examples of creating such a module?

Comment: I found my old matrial seaching for Azure Plugin Library. If anyone has more information feel free to share

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to [this article](http://coderead.wordpress.com/2012/05/21/azurepluginlibrary/) - although being old, this is currently the only way to build modules for Windows Azure.

And just to mention, modules are mostly used as a command line applications which are run via startup tasks.

The [Azure Plugin Library](http://richorama.github.io/AzurePluginLibrary/) itself is very life and active project.

Currently there is no other way to write "plugin-style" modules for Azure Cloud Services.

Comment: It was what I was looking for. I just needed to learn how to do a plugin for easier adding some extensions to our webroles. Currently we have a class that extends the RoleEntryPoint and we have to remember adding the correct settings. So creating a plugin would make this step easier.